# Dynamic array filtering by object property

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter

I have a react live search dropdown component that filters through an array of objects by a search term. It filters my objects by title and then returns a list of all the related objects. This works fine.

**Current:**

Data Structure

```
data: [
    { id: 1, title: 'Some title here' },
    { id: 2, title: 'Another title' },
    { id: 3, title: 'last title' },
]
```

Component

```
   <LiveSearch
        term={term}
        data={data} />
```

**Inside Live search component**

Filter data by term and render list

```
return data
        .filter(item => item.title.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
        .map((item, idx) => <li key={idx}>{item.title}</li>
```

My objects to search by are getting more advanced and what I would like to be able to do is pass into my component an array of property names I would like to compare to the search term.

My thinking process behind it is to loop through the object properties and if on of the properties matches the term the loop breaks and returns true adding that object to the list of items to be displayed.

**Goal**

Data Structure

```
data: [
    { id: 1, country: 'Canada', title: 'Some title here' },
    { id: 2, country: 'Australia', title: 'Another title' },
    { id: 3, country: 'Netherlands', title: 'last title' },
]
```

Component

```
<LiveSearch
   searchFields={['country', 'title']}
   term={term}
   data={data} />
```

Inside Component filtering

```
return data
         .filter(item => {
            // Dynamic filtering of terms here
         })
         .map((item, idx) => <li key={idx}>{item.title}</li>
```

Inside the filter I'm trying to get a loop through the array and dynamically produce logic similar to this

```
item.searchFields[0].toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase()) ||
item.searchFields[1].toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase())
```

But obviously could loop over an infinite number of searchfields/properties

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use [`Array#some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Something like

```
term = term.toLowerCase()
return data
  .filter(item => {
    return searchFields.some(field => item[field].toLowerCase().includes(term))
  }).map(...
```

Answer (score 1):

Check if `some` of the `searchFields` match:

```
// Checks wether a value matches a term
const matches = (value, term) => value.toLowerCase().includes(term.toLowerCase());

 // Checks wether one of the fields in the item matcues the term
 const itemMatches = (fields, term) => item => fields.some(field => matches(item[field], term);

 // Filter the data to only contain items where on of the searchFields matches the term
 const result = props.data.filter( itemMatches(props.searchFields, props.term) );

 return result.map(item => <li key={idx}>{item.title}</li>);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use Array `.some` combined with `.filter`

```
let result = data.filter(obj => 
  searchFields.some(s => 
  obj[s] != undefined && obj[s].toLowerCase() === term
));
```

```js
let data = [
    { id: 1, country: 'Canada', title: 'Some title here' },
    { id: 2, country: 'Australia', title: 'Another title' },
    { id: 3, country: 'Netherlands', title: 'last title' },
], searchFields = ["country", "title"], term = "canada";

let result = data.filter(obj => 
  searchFields.some(s => 
  obj[s] != undefined && obj[s].toLowerCase() === term
));

console.log(result);
```

Comment: That is really overcomplicating things.

Comment: @JonasWilms Possibly? That's not really a constructive comment. Care to elaborate?

Comment: That `flag` ? I mean you always check all the properties, you could actually exit after the first found.